# The application must supply JDBC connections - Deploy Play 2.4.2 (with JPA + Hibernate ) to Heroku

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, heroku, playframework

I'm trying to deploy a Play Framework (2.4.2) App to Heroku. I'm using JPA (with Hibernate 4.3.10 and Postgres). I'm also running JDK8.

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to provide as much info as I could.

I've been getting this error when I try to access the app:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
2015-09-18T09:23:46.533143+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:61) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
2015-09-18T09:23:46.533144+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
2015-09-18T09:23:46.533146+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
2015-09-18T09:23:46.533147+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
2015-09-18T09:23:46.533148+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
2015-09-18T09:23:46.533149+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
```

I poked around in [Hibernate's code and found the UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/internal/UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java) class and it appears to be working exactly as it should because the implementation just throws an Exception, which leads me to believe there's something wrong with the configuration as that class does nothing useful so I should never reach that code path.

I've followed the documentation on [how to deploy to heroku](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionHeroku)

As such, my Procfile is the following:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=false -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

I've also tried (notice the {}) without success

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port=$PORT -DapplyEvolutions.default=false -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL
```

My build.sbt file includes postgres and hibernate:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.10.Final",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41" withSources(),
  //other stuff
)
```

And my `application.conf` includes the following:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${?JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
db.default.username=${?JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
db.default.password=${?JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
db.default.jndiName=myDS
jpa.default=myDS
```

My persistence.xml file (in conf/META-INF) is the following (read bellow as to why there are no url/user/password properties on this file):

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="NoteDS" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>
        Persistence unit for the Weldnote Project
    </description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

     <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />


        <!-- Hibernate Properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

        <!-- Show SQL statements -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        <!-- Auto Update the database on Entity change -->
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="auto" /> -->

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

From what I read from the Heroku documentation (and also from Play's documentation, Heroku provides a `DATABASE_URL` in the environment which is a "non-standard format" but that Play understands. Although I found some reports that it does not work with JPA directly so you have to parse the url and set values. I found this [gist explaining how to parse the url](https://gist.github.com/mlecoutre/4088178) and created a `GlobalSetting` class to do just that (which I added to the `application.conf` under the key `application.global=org.example.GlobalSetting`.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;

public class GlobalSetting extends GlobalSettings{

@Override
public void beforeStart(Application app) {

    super.beforeStart(app);
    String databaseUrl = System.getenv("DATABASE_URL");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(databaseUrl, ":@/");
    String dbVendor = st.nextToken(); //if DATABASE_URL is set
    String userName = st.nextToken();
    String password = st.nextToken();
    String host = st.nextToken();
    String port = st.nextToken();
    String databaseName = st.nextToken();

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"));

    System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", databaseUrl);
    System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", userName);
    System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
    System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    System.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"));



}

}
```

I know the class is working because the println are appearing in Heroku's Logs. I've tried many variations with various degrees of failure. It seems clear to me that it's something related to the configuration of the datasource/database somehow, but I haven't been able to figure it any help would be appreciated.

Locally I had a working application but using the standard configuration for Play (no DATABASE_URL), I've tried matching the configurations for Heroku in the local play environment and the problem seems to be the same.

I've googled a lot (and found several question here on stackoverflow that have the same symptom but I cannot track down what might be causing this in my particular situation)

**EDIT**:

With the pointers from @codefinger and a lot more googling I've made a breakthrough, but I don't understand why it works this way.

While trying to make the application work locally, I've found out that it didn't work with the DATABASE_URL so I followed @codefinger's suggestions and the problem remained the same (i.e running `heroku local web`), but if I had my properties in the persistence.xml file everything worked fine (running `activator run`). By chance I tried the following in the GlobalSettings file:

```
System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME"));
System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD"));
System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
System.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME"));
System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD"));
```

By passing the `javax.persistence.*` **AND** `hibernate.connection.*` connection properties apparently it can now access the database. 
But I can't seem to understand while running locally with only the `javax.persitence.*` properties on the `persistence.xml` file it works fine.

I'm continuing my experiments to try and find what would be the appropriate configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested this with a `DATABASE_URL` env var locally? I'm not certain that your parsing of `DATABASE_URL` is correct. Here is a [library that will do it for you](https://github.com/jkutner/heroku-jdbc), which you can include in your `build.sbt` like this:

```
"com.heroku.sdk" % "heroku-jdbc" % "0.1.1"
```

In general, it's doing this:

```
val dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
val username = dbUri.getUserInfo.split(":")(0)
val password = dbUri.getUserInfo.split(":")(1)
val dbUrl = s"jdbc:postgresql://${dbUri.getHost}:${dbUri.getPort()}${dbUri.getPath}"
```

Alternatively, you can just use `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` in your `Global` class (note that the code below is only for example as it doesn't check for `null`s):

```
System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_USER"));
System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD"));
```

I'd recommend adding a `DATABASE_URL` entry to your the file `.env` in the root directory of your project like so:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/dbName
```

Then build your app with `sbt stage` and run it with `heroku local web`. This will allow you to easily test with the `DATABASE_URL`.

The Heroku `DATABASE_URL` actually follows the [libpq standard for connection strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING). But most JDBC libraries only work with a JDBC URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply codefinger, with your input I wasn't able to make it work but it set me on a different course. I've posted my findings on the original post, do you have an idea of what could it be?